# Diferente resultado con asignación o sin asignación en operador ternario

Tags: php

¿Por qué los ternarios en PHP presentan 2 respuestas diferentes a 2 líneas casi idénticas dentro de un echo? Éstas son las dos líneas:

```
echo true ?    'a1':    'a2' ?'b':3?'d':'e';  //devuelve el echo d

echo true ? $a='a1': $a='a2' ?'b':3?'d':'e'; // devuelve el echo a1
```

La única diferencia el primero no asigna valor, en la segunda asigna el valor.

Comment: Hola Ivan, bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español y enhorabuena por tu primera pregunta. Completa el [tour] para aprender más sobre el sitio y su funcionamiento en general (y así ganar una medalla). Un saludo.

Answer (score 1):

Estos resultados tienen que ver con la [precedencia de operadores](http://php.net/manual/es/language.operators.precedence.php) y porque se están acumulando los operadores ternarios (algo que se recomienda evitar en la [documentación oficial de PHP](http://php.net/manual/es/language.operators.comparison.php#example-146) porque los resultados pueden ser inesperados como en este caso).

Voy a poner paréntesis en las expresiones de arriba para que se vea qué es lo que realmente se está ejecutando.

La primera expresión quedaría así:

```
echo (((true ? 'a1' : 'a2') ? 'b' : 3) ? 'd': 'e');
```

Que es por lo que obtienes el resultado `d`. Porque sea lo que sea lo que haya en los paréntesis ('b'), va a considerarse verdadero, por lo que va a devolver 'd'.

La segunda expresión quedaría así:

```
echo (true ? $a ='a1' : ($a='a2' ? 'b' : (3 ? 'd' : 'e')));
```

como `true` es cierto, se irá por la primera rama que es `$a = 'a1'`. Y el resultado de la asignación es el valor asignado. Por eso devuelve 'a1'.

Comment: Yo siempre utilizo los parentesis pero me pasaron preguntas de examen de certificación de PHP,  y buscaban cual es el resultado de una expresión similar sin los parentesis. Y le coloque las variables para buscar que es lo que ocurre. Y quede mas confundido y le estoy buscando sentido de como se evaluan estas expresiones, dentro de PHP.